# Rails Backbone Render Nested JSON in jst.eco template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, underscore.js, eco

I have this set JSON data

**JSON**

```
[{
    "country": {
        "name": "Malaysia",
        "total_amount": 0.0,
        "count": 0
    }
}, {
    "country": {
        "name": "Philippines",
        "total_amount": 0.0,
        "count": 0
    }
}, {
    "country": {
        "name": "Thailand",
        "total_amount": 0.0,
        "count": 0
    }
}]
```

Let say this data I sent it like

```
.replaceWith(@template(data: @data_transaction)
```

How do I retrieve the data inside the **template.jst.eco**

I have tried to use this kind of for loop

```
<% for key, data in @data_transaction.models: %>
   <%= data.get("country").name %>
   <%= data.get("country").total_amount %>
   <%= data.get("country").count %>
```

it just does not work

if I tried to print it out this way inside the template.jst.eco

```
<%= @data_transaction %>
```

it will show this kind of things

```
[object, object]
```

Any helps?

Thank you very  much

Answer (score 1):

I fear you made a very common mistake.

Try to replace:

```
for key, data in @data_transaction.models:
```

with:

```
for object in @data_transaction.models:
  for key, data of object:
```

Comment: hi Thanks for the reply, that **of** does work inside the backbone-view. But it does not work in template.jst.eco.

Comment: seems, the **template.jst.eco** does not recognize the **of**. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I think it stems from the fact you have an array then an object so you must loop the single element array THEN loop the object

Comment: hmm i dont really get it, so is it kind of nested loop ?
Could you help me out with sample. thank you very much

Comment: I got this error,
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**
I think its from the `for object in @data_transaction.models:`